# Повторяющийся CSS элемент фона через строго определенный промежуток?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, есть ли возможность средствами CSS задавать повторяющуюся лилию через каждые `400px` высоты?

[image: Повторяющаяся лилия]

Чтобы в независимости от размеров устройства, с которого смотрели, линия повторялась через определенный промежуток.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения нужного результата Вы можете воспользуйтесь функцией [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.stripe {
  height: 1900px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent 99%,
    #000 99%
  );
  background-size: 100% 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stripe"></div> 
</div>
```